# Error 1 Expression expected.(While Using SUB)

Tags: database, vb.net

I tried writing the below code for SQLite DB, but i get an error station Expression expected with Sub Underlined in `Params.ForEach(Sub(x) SQLCmd.Paramas.Add(x))`. I tried to figure out the issue but, i came to know that there is error in compiler in VB2008. Please any one help me to resolve this issue, or suggest me with alternative code for the above line

```vb
Public Sub ExecQuery(ByVal Query As String)
    Try
        SQLcon.Open()

        SQLCmd = New SQLiteCommand(Query, SQLcon)

        Params.ForEach(Sub(x) SQlCmd.Parameters.Add(x))

        Params.Clear()


        SQLDS = New DataSet
        SQLDA = New SQLiteDataAdapter(SQLCmd)
        RecordCount = SQLDA.Fill(SQLDS)


        SQLcon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exception = ex.Message
    End Try

    If SQLcon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then SQLcon.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with your code (assuming `Params` is a `List(Of T)`), but the alternative would be a [`For Each`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) statement?!

Comment: I treid removing Params, but encounterd an error saying ForEach is not declared

Comment: What is Params?  Is it a List(Of T)?  A Dictionary?

Comment: Yes it is List(Of T), as am very new to vb

Comment: @Mark How to write a code instead of List(Of T). Please guide me. I searched a lot but couldn't get any. Please that piece code will resole my issue, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are struggling with, but `ForEach` only works with some collections (arrays and `IList` I think), while a traditional `For Each` loop will work with any collection.  e.g. `For Each p In Params: SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(p): Next` (I wouldn't recommend combining all on one line like that, but comments are limited!).  If you are looking for something else, please clarify your question.

Comment: @Mark the problem is am very new to this application development. Am struggling to connect my toradex module with db4free server account to access data. I would like to connect to you in person so that i can learn more. My skype id would be ashi.mahe. Please help me in this