# Expression expected on using Sub code in VS2005 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

im having an error using sub says "Expression expected" pointing the word "Sub" with underline . Im using VS2005

```
    Params.ForEach(Sub(p) SQlCmd.Parameters.Add(p))
    Params.Clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use LINQ in a version of VB that was released before LINQ existed.  If I remember correctly, you'd need at least VB 2008 to use LINQ and at least VB 2010 to use the `Sub` keyword for a lambda, as VB initially only supported value lambdas, i.e. required you to use `Function` and return a value.

Comment: im using it for my sql control

Comment: [here is the link sir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29019550/error1expression-expected-while-using-sub)

we have the same problem

Comment: please help me here @jmcilhinney

Comment: I've already helped you.  You can't use LINQ in VB 2005.  Either upgrade to a new version of VB or don't use LINQ.